# Swift returning the indexes that will sort an array (similar to numpy argsort)

Tags: sorting, swift, numpy

I'm trying to return the indices of an array which correspond to the sorted values. For example,

```
let arr = [7, 10, -3]
let idxs = argsort(arr) // [2, 0, 1]
```

My attempt works but is not pretty, and only functions for CGFloat. I'm looking for some ways in which I can improve the function, make it generic and easier to read. The code just looks ugly,

```
func argsortCGFloat( a : [CGFloat] ) -> [Int] {

    /* 1. Values are wrapped in (index, values) tuples */
    let wrapped_array = Array(Zip2(indices(a),a))

    /* 2. A comparator compares the numerical value from 
       two tuples and the array is sorted */
    func comparator(a: (index : Int, value : CGFloat), b: (index : Int, value : CGFloat)) -> Bool {
        return a.value < b.value
    }
    var values = sorted(wrapped_array, comparator)

    /* 3. The sorted indexes are extracted from the sorted 
       array of tuples */
    var sorted_indexes: [Int] = []
    for pair in values {
        sorted_indexes.append(pair.0)
    }

    return sorted_indexes
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating an array of indexes, and sorting them using the array from the outer context, like this:

```
func argsort<T:Comparable>( a : [T] ) -> [Int] {
    var r = Array(indices(a))
    r.sort({ a[$0] > a[$1] })
    return r
}

let arr = [7, 10, -3]
let idxs = argsort(arr)
println (idxs)
```

Comment: That's much nicer! However, can replace the for-loop with, `Array(indices(r))`. I think you can then reduce the body of the function to one line!